# KDE network applet icons too large

Tags: kde, high-dpi, kde-plasma-5

After a KDE update to 5.13, the icons in the KDE network manager applet are oversized. I have a HiDPI display with scaling set up, but this has never been a problem before. Is there any way to get these icons to a normal size again? (Other icons are work fine). I am running Arch if that matters.

[image: applet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

which theme are you using? I had the same problem with the kde arc dark theme and i solved it updating to the last version available on the developer's github page. Just run the Arc KDE Installer script, reboot, and done! Hope it helps.

Comment: Instead of running the entire script, the `rm ~/.cache/plasma-svgelements-Arc* ~/.cache/plasma_theme_Arc*.kcache` works too!